# python string concatenation split over two lines

Tags: python, string

```py
for don in open('list.txt', 'r'):
    myURL=don 
    myURL=myURL.replace("rep.php","")
    print(myURL+"test.php")
```

It's printing

```
http://www.blabla.com
blablabla.html
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your example is not really complete as you `print(url)` but we don't see where that variable `url` is defined.

Comment: Please include the input data. There is no way that script produces the output shown. We should see "test.php" in there either as a separate line or as the end of the last line.

Comment: Sometimes printing data helps. If you add `print("DEBUG", repr(myURL), repr(myURL.replace("rep.php",""))` you'll see the problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you iterate over a file handle, you get one line at a time **with any trailing newline characters**.  So, the line is probably `'http://www.blabla.com\n'`.  That's why, when you append `'blabla.html'`, the result is split over two lines.

An easy fix is to do

```py
print(myURL.rstrip() + 'blabla.html')
```

On a side note, it's good practice to manage resources like file handles with context blocks so that the file handle is explicitly closed (and not left to the garbage collector):

```py
with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    for don in f:
        ...
```